# Vue passing props to route components

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to pass data from the Vue instance through to components through router. I've tried to following along the docs and examples in stack overflow but can't get it to work.. I'm trying to pass a prop called "funds", below is my scripts and components:

main.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {
    App
  },
  data: {
    funds: [...]
  },
  template: '<App :funds="funds"/>'
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    ...
    <router-view :funds="funds" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'App'
  }
</script>

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
 routes: [
   ...
   {
     path: '/funds',
     name: 'funds',
     component: List
   }
 ]
})
```

List.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="fund in funds" :key="fund.name">
          ...
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'List',
    props: ['funds']
  }
</script>
```

I am seeing a warning in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "funds" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

However, when I run this I don't see any  rows in the table being rendered, in fact the table is just empty (only header). Am I missing something in the chain?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Updated. Hope it makes sense now :)

Comment: In App.vue, u need to define props too, props: ['funds']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **App.vue**, You need to add `props` too as shown below;

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    ...
    <router-view :funds="funds" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    props: ['funds']
  }
</script>

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
 routes: [
   ...
   {
     path: '/funds',
     name: 'funds',
     component: List
   }
 ]
})
```

Comment: Ah, the missing link! Thank you